# Quadratic integer Programming

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, integer-programming, convex-optimization

Would anyone mind helping me solve this problem

$$
\min\space f(x) = \frac12 x^\mathrm TQx + bx + c  \qquad \text{s.t. } \sum_i x_i=\lambda
$$

where $x$ is a vector whose entries are **positive integers** and $Q$ is **positive definite**.

Comment: In which context did you encounter this problem?

Comment: Actually the problem is that there are some integers which their summation is constant and I want to minimize the variance of them (which is a quadratic programming problem). I'm electrical engineering M.Sc. student. In my thesis I encountered this problem.

Comment: Could you tell us what exactly $Q$ and $b$ are? I think mathematica has some tools to help.

Comment: yes they are integer-valued. actually, Q= 2*(I + [1]), b=λe where I is the Identity matrix and [1] is a matrix who all its elements are 1 and e = [1 1 .... 1]'.

Comment: If you know the sum of n integers you know there average and the variance will be minimized with the integers as close to the average as possible so I think you will have to consider at most two integers, the two closest to the average or the average itself if that is an integer.

Comment: It looks like the right-hand side of the equation defining $f(x)$ is not well-formed, because the first term is a scalar (has 1 component) whereas $bx$ is a vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These kinds of (mixed) integer quadratic programming (MIQP) problems are typically solved by branch and bound algorithms.  One widely used commercial code is IBM's CPLEX.  You might also be interested in Sven Leyffer's MIQPBB code.

More general codes for mixed integer nonlinear programming (MINLP) can also be used for this problem.  See for example the BonMin code.